# Modifying listener file with script

Tags: shell, awk, sed

Below is my listener entry

`SID_LIST_DG_LISTENER =`
        `(SID_LIST =`
          `(SID_DESC =`
          `(GLOBAL_DBNAME = abc)`
          `(ORACLE_HOME = abc)`
           `(SID_NAME = abc)`
           `(SERVICE_NAME = abc)`
        `)`
        `)`
I want a shell command which can add a new SID DESC block.For example

`SID_LIST_DG_LISTENER =`
  `(SID_LIST =`
 `(SID_DESC =`
        `(GLOBAL_DBNAME = abc)`
        `(ORACLE_HOME = abc)`
        `(SID_NAME = abc)`
        `(SERVICE_NAME = abc)`

`(SID_DESC =`
        `(GLOBAL_DBNAME = xyz)`
        `(ORACLE_HOME = xyz)`
        `(SID_NAME = xyz)`
        `(SERVICE_NAME = xyz)`
       `)`
       `)`

Comment: `cat new_desc_file >> desc_file`

Comment: I cannot directly append as I need to add the new SID_DESC block under SID_LIST block.

Comment: Check your example - it is probably incorrect; missing closing of the 1st desc.

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume that the last 2 closing parentheses are alone in lines, the following should work:

```
awk '!/^)$/ {print}' <desc_file >new_desc_file
cat new_desc >> new_desc_file
printf ")\n)" >> new_desc_file
mv new_desc_file desc_file
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch this works , If you dont mind ,can it be done for both the cases ,like last 2 closing parentheses are on same line or it can be on different line.

Comment: What I was thinking like ,extract second last parentheses ,then add new block and finally add one closing parentheses.

Comment: Well, you can try one, multiline regex to make it more robust.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with sed, but the command is somewhat cryptic (as is often the case with sed):

```
SID=xyz
sed '3{N;N;N;N;h;};${s/)$//;p;g;s/abc/'$SID'/g;s/))$/)/;s/)$/))/;}' oldfile > newfile
```

This command works with both cases (two final parentheses on same line or different lines). And you may be able to edit the file in place, depending on your version of sed and OS.